# Dynamic directive from a directive's template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to load directives in my page, based on an array of directive names.

**In my main page:**

```
<div component-loader></div>
```

**Directive:**

```
myApp.directive('componentLoader', function($compile) {
    var component = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }

    return {
        link:           component,
        replace:        true,
        scope:          true,
        template:       '<div ng-repeat="component in components"><div {{component.directive}}></div></div>'
    };
});
```

**Scope:**

```
$scope.components = [{
    directive:  'directive01'
},{
    directive:  'directive02'
}]
```

**What I'm expecting:**

```
<div directive01></div>
<div directive02></div>
```

**What I'm getting:**

```
<div {{component.directive}}></div>
<div {{component.directive}}></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Binding only works for attribute contents, not attribute names (as far as I am aware).
Instead, you could have a template-less directive with element being generated in the link function.

```
<div component-loader="components"></div>
```

Your link function

```
function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var components = attrs.componentsLoader;
    // Or use scope.components or scope.$parent.components depending on
    // how your scopes are organised

    angular.forEach(components, function (component) {
        element.append(angular.element().attr(component.directive, '');
    });        

    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Still not an ideal solution, but it does what I wanted:

```
myApp.directive('componentLoader', function($compile) {
    var component = function(scope, element, attrs) {

        scope.$watchCollection('components', function(a, b) {
            var code = '';
            var i;
            for (i=0;i<scope.components.length;i++) {
                code += '<div '+scope.components[i].directive+'></div>'
            }
            element.html($compile(code)(scope));

        });

    }

    return {
        link:           component,
        scope:          true
    };
});
```